# Excel COUNTIF Not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I got a column with several rows containing `m` or `w`.

So I just want to count how many of that rows contain the letter `w`. This looks like a rather simple task but excel is throwing an error on me when I use the function like this:

`=COUNTIF(C2:C123, "w")`

> There`s a problem with this forlmula
>   When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula

I looked at the documentation of the formula:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

It seems that I'm doing nothing wrong here. What is causing this type of error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears microsoft decided that parameters are not longer seperated by using `,` instead I have to use `;`.

I haven't noticed that because I'm not using excel very often, but it seemed to be faster than writing a script for that task.

Comment: While your issue is resolved, it appears that the 'List Separator' character in your Windows-->Control Panel-->Region and Language-->Additional Settings-->Number-->List Separator is a semicolon instead of comma. Try changing it back to comma and your formula in Excel should work fine with with comma as a separator. You may need to restart Excel after this change is done in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Not posting as a solution necessarily, but posting a noteworthy observation:

[image]

The formula does in fact use a comma and not a semicolon. Semicolons I generally see in programming languages to indicate an "end of line" or "end of sentence".

Comment: different regional settings can determine whether you use a comma, or semi colon, so the formula can technically use either. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjI_d7gzNPdAhWnIMAKHW42CaQQFjACegQICxAK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fakbaraji.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F05%2F29%2Fthe-comma-and-semicolon-issue-in-excel-due-to-regional-settings-when-open-csv-file%2F&usg=AOvVaw2v8T6qhLXNrZRd7gKJRqSi